# "There are no type variables left" after union of Pydantic models

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I'm doing some fancy type-related shenanigans and have defined three responses from my API.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Literal, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Success(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    status: Literal["success"] = "success"
    data: T

class Fail(BaseModel):
    status: Literal["fail"] = "fail"
    message: str

class Error(BaseModel):
    status: Literal["error"] = "error"
    message: str
    code: int | None
```

The general form of these is a union:

```
Response = Success[T] | Fail | Error
```

which I would like to also be generic, so my handler function signatures can use a specific type, like

```
def some_handler(message: str) -> Response[int]:
   return Fail(message=message)
   # the body of this function is actually irrelevant to the error
```

However, doing so gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam_smith/tmp/test/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    def some_handler(message: str) -> Response[int]:
TypeError: There are no type variables left in __main__.Success | __main__.Fail | __main__.Error
```

This is notable because if I drop BaseModel from each class, it works as expected

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Literal, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Success(Generic[T]):
    status: Literal["success"] = "success"
    data: T

class Fail:
    status: Literal["fail"] = "fail"
    message: str

class Error:
    status: Literal["error"] = "error"
    message: str
    code: int | None

Response = Success[T] | Fail | Error

def some_handler(message: str) -> Response[int]:
    return Fail(message=message)
# works!
```

Comment: This issue in the Pydantic github repo seems relevant https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6994

Comment: 1) Which Pydantic version are you using? 2) Please fix your code samples so that they _at the very least_ are syntactically correct. 3) Please make sure you included all relevant imports so that we actually have a [mcve]. 4) After fixing your syntax errors, I cannot reproduce the problem with Pydantic v1.

Comment: Aside from that, `Response` is not generic in your definition; it is missing a type parameter.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg apologies for the typos, I was transcribing across workstations. Fixed now. I'm using Pydantic v2, and the link I added in the comment seems to agree with you, also confirming that v1 does not display the same behavior. Likely down to a library bug! That said: your final comment is wrong -- Response is generic in my definition (which is why `Response[int]` is valid in Pydantic v1 or in the second code sample -- it simplifies to `Success[int] | Fail | Error`)

Comment: You are right about that last comment. My mistake. What is curious is that I am still getting a _different_ error with the exact code you provided using Pydantic `2.3.0` on Python `3.11.4`, namely `TypeError: Success | Fail | Error is not a generic class`. Pydantic v2 is changing rapidly right now, so even slight version differences can be important. Can you add the output of `python -c "import pydantic.version; print(pydantic.version.version_info())"` for reproducibility please? Also, in my case the error already disappears after dropping `BaseModel` only from `Success`.

Comment: Pydantic 2.3.0 (on Core 2.6.3) running on Python 3.10.12

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg though you're right! Dropping BaseModel from Success is sufficient to remove the error

Comment: It seems the error is in fact dependent on the Python minor version used. I added a MRE to the issue you linked. Pretty sure now that this is a Pydantic bug.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg just saw it. Thanks for adding to the discussion. I'll likely just drop runtime type checking for my responses for now -- they'll be generated by trusted code anyway. Vanilla dataclasses will do.

Comment: To be fair, you could sidestep the issue for now by just not using the type alias. In this case, instead of using `Response[int]` as the return type you could use `Success[int] | Fail | Error` directly. I get that this will be annoying, if you reused `Response` in many locations, but it would work around the issue for the time being.